# escalante-run gives error when using scala 2.10

Tags: sbt, escalante

I run `escalante-run` and I get the below error:

Note that the xml file it tries to read is incomplete:

```
cat  /var/folders/8n/ws0wh0wd4vg5tf80b_kpq5_r0000gq/T/escalante-0.2.0/modules/org/scala-lang/scala-library/2.10.0/module.xml

<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
```

End of file and this is the error:

```
WARN: Artifact not found (exception: Could not find artifact net.liftweb:lift-json-ext_2.10.0:jar:2.5-RC2 in central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)), but Scala version old (UnknownScalaVersion(2.10.0)), so with a more recent one: SCALA_292
Mar 29, 2013 3:22:32 AM org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceLogger_$logger startFailed
  ERROR: MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.module.service."deployment.ROOT.war".main
org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.module.service."deployment.ROOT.war".main: JBAS018759: Failed to load module: deployment.ROOT.war:main
at org.jboss.as.server.moduleservice.ModuleLoadService.start(ModuleLoadService.java:92)
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Caused by: org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoadException: Error loading module from /var/folders/8n/ws0wh0wd4vg5tf80b_kpq5_r0000gq/T/escalante-0.2.0/modules/org/scala-lang/scala-library/2.10.0/module.xml
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleXmlParser.parseModuleXml(ModuleXmlParser.java:293)
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleXmlParser.parseModuleXml(ModuleXmlParser.java:243)
at org.jboss.modules.LocalModuleLoader.parseModuleInfoFile(LocalModuleLoader.java:138)
at org.jboss.modules.LocalModuleLoader.findModule(LocalModuleLoader.java:122)
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.loadModuleLocal(ModuleLoader.java:275)
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.preloadModule(ModuleLoader.java:222)
at org.jboss.modules.LocalModuleLoader.preloadModule(LocalModuleLoader.java:94)
at org.jboss.modules.Module.addPaths(Module.java:851)
at org.jboss.modules.Module.link(Module.java:1206)
at org.jboss.modules.Module.relinkIfNecessary(Module.java:1235)
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.loadModule(ModuleLoader.java:208)
at org.jboss.as.server.moduleservice.ModuleLoadService.start(ModuleLoadService.java:71)
... 5 more
  Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[2,1]
Message: Premature end of file.
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl.next(XMLStreamReaderImpl.java:594)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl.nextTag(XMLStreamReaderImpl.java:1235)
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleXmlParser.parseDocument(ModuleXmlParser.java:540)
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleXmlParser.parseModuleXml(ModuleXmlParser.java:288)
... 16 more
  Mar 29, 2013 3:22:32 AM org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentHandlerUtil$1$2 handleResult
  ERROR: JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "ROOT.war" was rolled back with the following failure message:
  {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.module.service.\"deployment.ROOT.war\".main" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.module.service.\"deployment.ROOT.war\".main: JBAS018759: Failed to load module: deployment.ROOT.war:main
    Caused by: org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoadException: Error loading module from /var/folders/8n/ws0wh0wd4vg5tf80b_kpq5_r0000gq/T/escalante-0.2.0/modules/org/scala-lang/scala-library/2.10.0/module.xml
    Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[2,1]
    Message: Premature end of file."}}
    Mar 29, 2013 3:22:32 AM org.jboss.as.server.deployment.AbstractDeploymentUnitService stop
    INFO: JBAS015877: Stopped deployment ROOT.war in 32ms
    [trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last *:escalante-run for the full output.
    [error] (*:escalante-run) org.jboss.as.controller.client.helpers.standalone.ServerDeploymentHelper$ServerDeploymentException: java.lang.Exception: {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.module.service.\"deployment.ROOT.war\".main" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.module.service.\"deployment.ROOT.war\".main: JBAS018759: Failed to load module: deployment.ROOT.war:main
    [error]     Caused by: org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoadException: Error loading module from /var/folders/8n/ws0wh0wd4vg5tf80b_kpq5_r0000gq/T/escalante-0.2.0/modules/org/scala-lang/scala-library/2.10.0/module.xml
    [error]     Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[2,1]
    [error] Message: Premature end of file."}}
    [error] Total time: 8 s, completed Mar 29, 2013 3:22:32 AM
```

Comment: I've upgraded Escalante to Scala 2.10 and in doing so I found some issues that could lead to a VerifyError runtime error due to multiple commons-code jar files (see http://issues.jboss.org/browse/ESC-18). So, if you wanna use Scala 2.10, I'd highly recommend using a 0.3.0-SNAPSHOT version. There's no SNAPSHOTs for this version uploaded yet, but I'm uploading one as we speak...

Comment: A 0.3.0-SNAPSHOT is now up. Can you give it a go?

Comment: I set escalanteVersion := "0.3.0-SNAPSHOT" in build.sbt, but after deleting .ivy2/cache/io.escalante, and reloading sbt, I see that it is downloading downloading http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/io/escalante/escalante-dist/0.2.0/escalante-dist-0.2.0.zip  (which I was hoping it would not happen), I'll see if once it is done it works anyway or now. Thanks

Comment: now I get: https://gist.github.com/fmpwizard/5316092

Comment: Diego, apologies for the delay getting back. I had other priorities that needed my attention last couple of weeks. The ZIP error you got, is that related to trying to unzip `0.3.0-SNAPSHOT`? Did you manage to get around the issue where it was still downloading version 0.2.0?

Comment: Ok, I think I know what happened. For the first issue, I guess the problem is that you defined `escalanteVersion` version before `escalanteSettings` and so it was being overriden by default value. For the latter ZIP error issue, I was making a wrong assumption about downloading a new Escalante version, which is a bug

Comment: Ok, I've sort out the issue in https://github.com/escalante/sbt-escalante/issues/13 so that you can use a different Escalante version, but version 0.3.0 has issues with the code used to start it up (arquillian), so a new plugin is needed to run 0.3.0-SNAPSHOT. I'm working on a new version of the SBT plugin anyway, which will default to 0.3.0, so need to wait a little longer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Diego, [Escalante 0.3.0 is out now](http://goo.gl/fG0B6) with Scala 2.10 support. This version solves the Scala 2.10 issue you had. Let me know how that goes :).

Comment: Wicked, glad to hear that :)))